# Combo <Select> não funciona

Tags: javascript, menu, combobox

Preciso que o segundo `<select>` receba os dados de acordo com a escolha do primeiro. Aparecem os `<option>` no primeiro `<select>`, mas no segundo nem se mexe.

Tenho uma pasta `textdata` com todos *.txt* referente aos `<option>` de cada correspondência.

HTML

```
<select id="first-choice">
  <option selected value="0">>>> Selecione</option>
  <option value="AC">AC</option>
  <option value="AL">AL</option>
  <option value="AM">AM</option>
  <option value="AP">AP</option>
  <option value="BA">BA</option>
  <option value="CE">CE</option>
  <option value="DF">DF</option>
  <option value="ES">ES</option>
  <option value="GO">GO</option>
  <option value="MA">MA</option>
  <option value="MG">MG</option>
  <option value="MS">MS</option>
  <option value="MT">MT</option>
  <option value="PA">PA</option>
  <option value="PB">PB</option>
  <option value="PE">PE</option>
  <option value="PI">PI</option>
  <option value="PR">PR</option>
  <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
  <option value="RN">RN</option>
  <option value="RO">RO</option>
  <option value="RR">RR</option>
  <option value="RS">RS</option>
  <option value="SC">SC</option>
  <option value="SE">SE</option>
  <option value="SP">SP</option>
  <option value="TO">TO</option>
  <option value="WW">WW</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second-choice">
  <option>Selecionar UF</option>
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
   $("#second-choice").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
});
</script>
```

Uma parte de um dos arquivos *.txt*

```
<option>São Paulo - SP001</option>
<option>Adamantina - SP002</option>
<option>Adolfo - SP003</option>
<option>Aguaí - SP004</option>
<option>Águas da Prata - SP005</option>
```

Comment: Pq está carregando 2 jquerys diferentes ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Tente colocar o segundo parametro do `.load()` para dar um alert informando se o carregamento foi feito com sucesso ou não, ajuda bastante a descobrir.

Comment: Os valores do 1º select estão em maiúsculo, logo os nomes dos .txt tb devem ser maiúsculos (ex. AC.txt, SP.txt etc...) caso contrário não encontrará. Ou então vc pode converter para minúsculo os valores: `$(this).val().toLowerCase()`

Comment: @Sam não tenho uma explicação lógica pra isso. Todos txt tão com maiúsculas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, a princípio o seu código está correto. O que pode está acontecendo, é que os seus arquivos .txt não estejam dentro de um server HTTP e por isso o jQuery não os carrega. Instala a extensão [Web Server](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) no Chrome e configura ele para servir os arquivos das suas pastas. Minha estrutura de pastas ficou assim:

```
C:\stackoverflow\exemplo01
C:\stackoverflow\exemplo01\index.html
C:\stackoverflow\exemplo01\textdata\AC.txt
```

Configurei o Web Server para servir os arquivos da pasta *C:\stackoverflow*.

Daí, só você acessar no browser a sua pasta usando a URL do Web Server:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8887/exemplo01/
```

O seu código está correto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu tava testando pelo Dreamweaver, o arquivo `teste1.php` na área de trabalho e junto da pasta `textdata` com os txt em letra maiúscula. Nada funciona, mesmo se coloco no servidor, não funciona http://viacircular.com.br/cesar/2018/teste1.php

Comment: O problema que está ocorrendo é que como você colocou o seu js  
para carregar em tempo de renderização do _DOM_, quando você  
usar o seletor **#first-choice**, ele ainda não está carregado  
para fazer o bind do evento de _change_.  
Solucao:  
   `$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#first-choice").change(function() {
      $("#second-choice").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
     });
    });`  
Coloca os teus imports de js sempre no final de todo seu HTML antes do fechamento da tag body.

Comment: Fiz assim mas ainda nada http://viacircular.com.br/cesar/2018/teste2.php